# Node.js VM and string concatenation

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I have an HTML file thats dynamically generated and only has a javascript object commented out. I'm trying to read that file, take the object out as a string, and run it with VM's `runInNewContext()`. But I run into a few hurdles.

Heres my code:

The file I have to read:

```
/*
{
  "userId": ["2897599"],
  "addressId": ["1287124"]
}
*/
```

The code I'm trying to use:

```
var startDataMap = body.indexOf('{')
    , endDataMap = body.indexOf('}')
    , dataMap    = body.substring(startDataMap, endDataMap);

  var sandbox = {};
  try { 
    vm.runInNewContext(dataMap, sandbox) 
  } catch (error) { 
      console.log(error) 
  };
```

If I run this it'll kick back an error of: 
`[SyntaxError: Unexpected token :]`

If I run it with a regex (ie with `(/\{/)` instead of `('{')` ) it will execute without an error but it doesnt catch the data.

**Question: Why will neither attempt work and how can I get the data I need using VM?**

---

Update:

I took the advice of the answer below and it removed the error and added a tweak or two. Here is the updated code:

```
var startDataMap = body.indexOf('{')
    , endDataMap = body.indexOf('*/', startDataMap)
    , dataMap    = body.substring(startDataMap, endDataMap);

  var sandbox = {};
  try { 
    vm.runInNewContext( '(' + dataMap + ')', sandbox) 
  } catch (error) { 
      console.log(error) 
  };
```

It removes the error but `sandbox` is still empty. I checked `dataMap` and it does have the required data but there is a line of whitespace at the end. Will this throw VM off? If so, how can I get rid of it, or do I need to alter my `endDataMap` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to add parentheses, so that the string is interpreted as an object instead of a block:

```
vm.runInNewContext("(" + dataMap + ")", sandbox)
```

Curly braces that are not in an expression are treated a blocks. By placing the code inside of parentheses, you make it clear that the code should be an object literal, rather than a block.

Comment: Odd. Never knew that. So that fixed the error. However I still have nothing in `sandbox`.  I checked what I was getting in `dataMap` and its the right data but there is whitespace at the end. Would that impact things? If so, how can I get rid of it? I'll update the code to show the slight tweaks I made

Comment: It occurred to me that I was just dealing with a simple object, so I just switched to `JSON.parse` works perfectly. I'm still curious on why it didnt work though.